List of mantras that can be chanted by anyone - does this have a scriptural backing?
Let me just quote a part of a book called 'The Ancient Science of Mantras' by a certain 'Om Swami' that I was reading.
QUOTE
Rudrayamalam and other scriptures are quite clear on the
mantras that don’t need special assessments. Here are the
mantras that don’t require any compatibility or other
considerations in the Kali Yuga.

A mantra your guru has initiated you in
Any mantra of Krishna
A mantra that’s given to you in a dream
When a mantra is imparted by a female adept even
not as
initiation
A mantra comprising only one seed syllable
A mantra comprising only three seed syllables
A mantra that contains more than twenty letters
All vedic mantras (There are a lot of non-vedic
mantras)
A mantra of five letters
A mantra of eight letters

For any mantra to be effective, particularly if it doesn’t
fall in the above ten categories, it requires initiation, proper
invocation and complete adherence to the tenets of mantra
yoga.
UNQUOTE
Which parts of the Rudra Yamala or other scriptures actually declare this? Is this advice valid? Can anyone give me actual references to back up the validity of this? The author claims this to be clear advice from the scriptures, but this basically goes against everything I've ever read regarding initiation etc. I'm open to being proved completely wrong and especially unititiated sadhaks stand to benefit greatly if this advice is indeed true and correct.

For anyone interested in following the discussion - https://www.reddit.com/r/hinduism/comments/1e0q65g/list_of_mantras_that_can_be_chanted_by_anyone_is/
